# Laravel Sort Model based on relationship values

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model called Business, a business can have several services they provide. I have another model called Payments. Payment holds a record of what service people pay for. A service can have many Payments. I intend to fetch top 10 and worst 10 businesses based on payments received. The code below works fine, but it is very inefficient. I have to loop through the whole data to retrieve the information I need. Any more efficient way of achieving this?

```js
$businesses = Business::with(['services'])->get();
foreach($businesses as $business){
    $id = $business->id;
    $name = $business->display_name;
    $services = $business->services;
    $businessRevenue = 0;
    if(count($services)>0){
        foreach($services as $service){
            $serviceId = $service->id;
            $totalAmount = PaymentTransaction::whereHas('invoice', function($query) use ($serviceId){
                $query->where('product_code_id', $serviceId);
            })->where('amount_paid', ">", 0)->sum('amount_paid');
            $businessRevenue= $businessRevenue + $totalAmount;
        }
    }
    $businessArray = (object) array('id'=> $id, 'name'=> $name, 'revenue'=> $businessRevenue);
    
    array_push($transformedBusiness, $businessArray);
}
$topBusiness = $bottomBusiness = $transformedBusiness;
usort($bottomBusiness, function($a, $b) {return strcmp($a->revenue, $b->revenue);});
usort($topBusiness, function($a, $b) {return strcmp($b->revenue, $a->revenue);});
$topBusiness = array_slice($topBusiness, 0, 10);
$bottomBusiness = array_slice($bottomBusiness, 0, 10);
return view('report.department_performance', compact('topBusiness', 'bottomBusiness'));
```

Comment: First of all use `Business::has('services')->get()` instead of `Business::with('services')->get()` This way you don't need to control `count($services)>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use a join query to get top and lowest 10 businesses directly from database instead of looping all business records and manually calculate their revenue

For top 10 business you can use inner joins for rest of the related tables

```
$topBusinesses = DB::query()
      ->select('b.id', 'b.display_name',  DB::raw('sum(p.amount_paid) as revenue')
      ->from('business as b')
      ->join('service as s', 'b.id', '=', 's.business_id')
      ->join('invoice as i', 's.id', '=', 'i.product_code_id')
      ->join('payment_transaction as p', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('p.id', '=', 'i.payment_transaction')
                     ->where('p.amount_paid', '>', 0);
      })
      ->groupBy('b.id', 'b.display_name')
      ->orderByDesc('revenue')
      ->limit(10)
      ->get();
```

For lowest 10 business use left joins for invoice and payment_transaction so that if there are no records in these table for a business you will still get these business records

```
$lowestBusinesses = DB::query()
      ->select('b.id', 'b.display_name',  DB::raw('coalesce(sum(p.amount_paid),0) as revenue')
      ->from('business as b')
      ->join('service as s', 'b.id', '=', 's.business_id')
      ->leftJoin('invoice as i', 's.id', '=', 'i.product_code_id')
      ->leftJoin('payment_transaction as p', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('p.id', '=', 'i.payment_transaction')
                     ->where('p.amount_paid', '>', 0);
       })
      ->groupBy('b.id', 'b.display_name')
      ->orderBy('revenue')
      ->limit(10)
      ->get();
```

I have used MySQL [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to show 0 value in case `sum()` returns null, If you are using any other database you can use an alternate function.

Comment: $lowestBusinesses = DB::query()
      ->select('b.id', 'b.display_name',  DB::raw('coalesce(sum(p.amount_paid),0) as revenue'))
      ->from('business as b')
      ->join('service as s', 'b.id', '=', 's.business_id')
      ->leftJoin('invoice as i', 's.id', '=', 'i.product_code_id')
      ->leftJoin('payment_transaction as p', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('i.id', '=', 'p.payment_invoice_id')
                     ->where('p.amount_paid', '>', 0);
       })
      ->groupBy('b.id', 'b.display_name')
      ->orderBy('revenue')
      ->limit(10)
      ->get();

Comment: The above returned 5 items instead of 10. There is no column on the invoice table that relates to the payment table. But there is a column on payment table that relates to invoice (payment_invoice_id).

Comment: @mykoman Are you sure you have morethan 5 records in database moreover try changing join of services table to `leftJoin('service as s)`